# C++ undefined reference to template method

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, methods, inline

I am trying to invoke a method of one class in a method of another class. The following code is working, but when I define the **Invoke method** of **class Second** in a separate **.cpp** file and **not inline** like it is now, I get the following error:
**undefined reference to 'void Second::Invoke(First*, TMethodDelegate::OneParam::TMethodPtr_Const)'**. Can anyone explain it to me why the **Invoke** method works only when it is defined **inline**?

```
// MethodDelegate.h
#pragma once

template <class TClass>
class TMethodDelegate
{
public:
    /** TMethodDelegate with no parameters */
    template <typename TRetValue>
    class NoParams
    {
    public:
        typedef TRetValue(TClass::*TMethodPtr)();
        typedef TRetValue(TClass::*TMethodPtr_Const)() const;

    private:
        inline NoParams() {}
    };

    /** TMethodDelegate with one parameter */
    template <typename TRetValue, typename TParam0>
    class OneParam
    {
    public:
        typedef TRetValue(TClass::*TMethodPtr)(TParam0);
        typedef TRetValue(TClass::*TMethodPtr_Const)(TParam0) const;

    private:
        inline OneParam() {};
    };

private:
    inline TMethodDelegate() {}
};

// First.h
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class First
{
public:
    inline void PrintInt(int number) const
    {
        cout << number << endl;
    }
};

// Second.h
#pragma once

#include "MethodDelegate.h"

class Second
{
public:
    // When defined in a separate .cpp file I get an undefined error when I am trying to call the method in the main function
    template <class TClass>
    inline void Invoke(TClass* object, typename TMethodDelegate<TClass>::template OneParam<void, int>::TMethodPtr_Const Func)
    {
        if (object != 0 && Func != 0)
        {
            int number = 10;
            (object->*Func)(number);
        }
    }
};

// main.cpp
#include "First.h"
#include "Second.h"

int main()
{
    First first;
    Second second;

    second.Invoke(&first, &First::PrintInt); // I get the error at this line. If I comment the line - the code is compiling. This is only if the Invoke method is defined in a separate .cpp file of course
}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't want to duplicate. I know template classes must be implemented in the header files, but I didn't know that this is also true for single template functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Template classes/functions must be defined in the header file, not in .cpp

see: [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: ...unless they are explicitly instantiated in said implementation file...

Comment: So it doesn't have to be inline, it just needs to be defined in the header file. Thank you very much again.